# How do I run a plist daemon on MAC OS 10.8.5 with the correct file permissions

Tags: python, macos, plist, daemon, file-permissions

I have a plist file saved to

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/local.WiFiDaemon.plist
```

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Disabled</key>
        <false/>
        <key>GroupName</key>
        <string>staff</string>
        <key>InitGroups</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>local.job</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>python</string>
                <string>/Library/Application Support/PythonDaemons/PythonTest.py</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/local.job.err</string>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/local.job.out</string>
        <key>UserName</key>
        <string>myuser</string>
</dict>
```

the file is supposed to execute a python script which just pings google and saves the results to a text file in:

```
/Library/Application Support/PythonDaemons/Ping_log.txt
```

the problem is the python script gives an error saying it doesn't have the permissions to the file. When I run the script from the command line everything works fine without any special permissions needed. What have I missed here?

Here's the python script:

```
import subprocess, datetime, time

host = "www.google.com"
ping = subprocess.Popen(
                        ["ping", "-c", "4", host],
                        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
out, error = ping.communicate()
with open('PingOut.txt', 'w') as outFile:
    outFile.write(out)
temp = out.split('\n')
parsed = temp[len(temp)-2].split('/')
min = parsed[len(parsed)-4].split(' ')[2]
avg = parsed[len(parsed)-3]
max = parsed[len(parsed)-2]

print "min: " + str(min) + "avg: " + str(avg) + "max: " + str(max)

with open('Ping_log.txt', 'a') as f:
 f.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + ',' + str(min) + ',' + str(avg) + ',' + str(max))
```

The permissions of the folder PythonDaemons is "drw-rw-rw-".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the full pathname of the log file:

```
with open('/Library/Application Support/PythonDaemons/Ping_log.txt', 'a') as f:
```

Or set the working directory in the plist:

```
<key>WorkingDirectory</key>
<string>/Library/Application Support/PythonDaemons</string>
```

Otherwise it defaults to a system directory that you don't have write permissions to.